# displaying XML data based on selection from a drop down list onchange

Tags: javascript, html, xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have an XML file that has data for home and away teams basically who is the home team, who is the away team and their scores and also the status of the game.

I am trying to use a table that is created in XSL and a select event to then display the specifics of a team that is selected from the drop down menu.  IE if you select the Blue Jays, it would display the 5 games on their schedule and if they have been played or not play yet.

The XML file structure is

```
 <ROOT>
      <TEAMS>
          <team>
      </TEAMS>

      <GAME>
          <home>
          <away>
          <home_score>
          <away_score>
      </GAME>
 </ROOT>
```

in my XSL file I have the following

```
 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" version="4.0" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
<xsl:template match="/ROOT">
    <table class="listing">
        <tr>select the team and press the Submit Team button</tr>
        <tr><th>Team</th>
            <td><select name="Team" class="listing" id="list" onchange=<xsl:apply-templates select="team" />
                <xsl:for-each select="TEAMS/team">
                    <option>
                        <xsl:value-of select="." />
                    </option>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </select>
            </td>
        </tr>

    </table>
</xsl:template>
        <xsl:template match="team">
    <select>
            <xsl:value-of select="Team" />
    </select>
</xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Then in the HTML file  I am loading the init() function in the body which is.

```
    function init()
    {
        var listElem=document.getElementById("list");
        listElem.innerHTML=runTransform(xmlDoc,xsltTeamDoc);


    }
```

I am trying to figure out if I can call another template for the "onchange" in XSL or call a function in javascript that can do the work.  This is where I am stuck.   how would this be accomplished in javascript?

Then display

```
<form name="sForm">
    <div id="list"></div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting a bit mixed up with the technologies here. It is not possible for the javascript "onchange" event to call an XSL template, or for XSL to call a javascript function in the browser. The two things don't run at the same time. You are calling a function to transform XML into HTML using XSLT, but once that transformation is done the XSLT is no longer running. It is gone and forgotten by the time the HTML appears in the browser. The browser will handle the HTML in the same way as if it had been originally written manually in a text editor.

Now, what you could do, is write out team information in separate **div** tags, which would be hidden using CSS styling. So, they would be on the page, but not visible. The "onchange" event would then just make these **div** tags visible based on the team selected.

So, start off by creating a template matching **Team** where you would output the games as you desire

```
<xsl:template match="Team">
    <div id="team-{.}" style="display:none">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="//GAME[home=current()]" />
    </div>
</xsl:template>
```

Note how the **div** is given an id based on the team name to uniquely identify it.

Then, after the existing code that creates the **table** element, you would call this template to render all the divs for all the teams.

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="TEAMS/Team" />
```

Then, the "onchange" event for your **select** would just consist of javascript to show the relevant **div**

```
<select name="Team" class="listing" id="list" 
        onchange="document.getElementById('team-' + this.value).style.display='block'">
```

Ideally, you would be using jquery here, but this purely to demonstrate the principle.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" version="4.0" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
<xsl:template match="/ROOT">
    <table class="listing">
        <tr>select the team and press the Submit Team button</tr>
        <tr><th>Team</th>
            <td><select name="Team" class="listing" id="list" onchange="document.getElementById('team-' + this.value).style.display='block'">
                <option>Choose Team</option>
                <xsl:for-each select="TEAMS/Team">
                    <option value="{.}">
                        <xsl:value-of select="." />
                    </option>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="TEAMS/Team" />
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="Team">
      <div id="team-{.}" style="display:none">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="//GAME[home=current()]" />
      </div>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="GAME">
      Date:<xsl:value-of select="Date" />
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This obviously still needs a lot of work, but it should point you in the right direction.

Comment: actually there is one thing now, I get the data to display but when I select a new team to display it just places another table below the old one.  How do I remove the previously selected table and only display the newly selected team?

Comment: That would be quite straight-forward if you were using JQuery. Just give each **div** tag a class of "team", for example, and do `$('.team').hide();` before you should the new team. If you can't work it out, feel free to ask a whole new question!